# Why is the past tense used in a clause related to the present

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

The background is that I was doing C1 tests and got wrong the following:

> It's time you ____ up your mind.

As it seems right to me, I wrote "*make*". However, the answer shows "*made*" as the correct answer.

Why is the past tense used?

I could understand the ussage of made if the word "already" was in the sentence. But it is not.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: That past tense construction does not have anything to do with "already", it is related to "It's time", see this for a more solid expiation: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/it-s-time

Comment: ok, I now understant, thank you!